# On $\eta(6z)\eta(18z)$ and the splitting / modularity of $x^3 - 2$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

Consider one of the simplest non-abelian examples of modularity. Let $$\eta(6z)\eta(18z) = q\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - q^{6n})(1 - q^{18n}) = q - q^7 - q^{13} -q^{19} + q^{25} + 2q^{31} - q^{37} + 2q^{43} - q^{61} - q^{67} - q^{73} - q^{79} + q^{91} - q^{97} - q^{103} \dots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n q^n$$

Then $a_p + 1 =$ the number of solutions of $\{x^3 - 2 = 0\}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, for prime $p > 3$.

1) What might be the best method to prove this?

2) Is it possible to prove it without knowledge of modular forms? i.e. without using the dimension / basis of the relevant space of moduli forms of some weight and level and nebentypus. For example, can it be explained using Weyl–Kac character formula etc.?

3) Unfortunately [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org) does not yet have a list of weight $1$ modular forms and their corresponding Artin representations. Where can we find more of such weight $1$ examples?

Comment: Small note: the same problem only with $x^3-x-1$ and $\eta(z)\eta(23z)$ is much more common in the literature, including on mathoverflow, so consider looking for that. Second, I think the level is 108 - the discriminant of the field. Third, the proofs using modular forms are pretty nice: use Hecke's results to prove that the polynomial "is modular", prove the eta product is modular, prove they are equal.

Comment: @DrorSpeiser Thanks. I was wondering if there can be a more direct proof, without using the dimension / basis of the relevant space of moduli forms of some weight and level and nebentypus.

Comment: That's your second question, I was more focused on the first ;)

Comment: As for more examples, LMFDB has a list of Artin representations, in which those with group equal to $S_3$ and trace of complex conjugation equal to 0 are all modular of weight 1 by the same method of proof, and satisfy a similar solution count property. In fact, all Artin reps. of dimension 2 with trace of complex conjugation equal to 0 are modular, and listed in the LMFDB. This follows from the Langlands-Tunnel theorem for "small" galois extensions, and from some more recent theorems that I don't know to whom to attribute to. (most of these by far will not have an eta product expansion)

Comment: For weight 1 modular forms you can look at http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lauder/weight1/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's an answer to 2. You can tell me if it's the "best method".

Euler's Pentagonal number theorem gives that
$$ \eta(24z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^{n} q^{(6n+1)^{2}}. $$
This yields the formula
$$ \eta(6z) \eta(18z) = \sum_{m, n \in \mathbb{Z}} (-1)^{m+n} q^{\frac{(6n+1)^{2} + 3(6m+1)^{2}}{4}}. $$
If $m=x$ and $n = x+2y$, then $m+n$ is even and we get
$$ \sum_{x, y \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{(6x+3y+1)^2 + 27y^{2}}. $$
On the other hand if $m=x$ and $n=x+2y+1$, then $m+n$ is odd and we get
$$ -\sum_{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{4(3x+y+1)^{2} + 2(3x+y+1)(2y+1) + 7(2y+1)^{2}}.$$

The upshot (skipping a few small details) is that
$$ \eta(6z) \eta(18z) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \sum_{x,y \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{x^{2} + 27y^{2}} - q^{4x^{2} + 2xy + 7y^{2}} \right]. $$

Now, Gauss proved that if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ is prime, then there is some $z$ so that $z^{3} \equiv 2 \pmod{p}$ if and only if $p = x^{2} + 27y^{2}$ for some $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$. It follows from this that the $p$th coefficient of $\eta(6z) \eta(18z)$ is $2$ if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $2$ is a cube modulo $p$.

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, but $2$ is not a cube modulo $p$, then $p$ is represented by $4x^{2} + 2xy + 7y^{2}$ in two ways, and this means that the $p$th coefficient of $\eta(6z) \eta(18z)$ is $-1$.

If $p \not\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$, the $p$th coefficient of $\eta(6z) \eta(18z)$ is clearly $0$.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that all such "classic" solutions I have seen involve theta series. Will it work for all $S_3$ representations (or maybe even more)?

Comment: I believe this method will work for all dihedral representations, and no others. The rough idea is that the space of weight 1 cusp forms spanned by differences of theta series should be decomposable into linear combinations of forms obtained from ray class characters of imaginary quadratic fields - these correspond by class field theory to dihedral extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: More precisely, dihedral extensions where complex conjugation acts by an element of determinant $-1$ -- otherwise you have to deal with ray class characters of real quadratic fields and you get Maas forms instead of modular forms.

Comment: Yes, that's right - only odd dihedral representations.