# Generalized partitions and eta functions

Tags: modular-forms, partitions

Let $\sigma$ be an element of $SL_{24}(\mathbb{Z})$ with its Jordan normal form is diagonal and the eigen values are $\epsilon_j$ for $1 \le j \le 24$ are n th root of unity where $n|N$ and $N$ is the finite order of  $\sigma$. Equivalently we are describing $\sigma$ through its cycle shape $(a_1)^{b_1}\cdots(a_s)^{b_s}$.

We associate $\sigma$ to the following modular form:

$$\eta_{\sigma}(q) := \eta(\epsilon_1q)\cdots\eta (\epsilon_{24} q)=\eta(q^{a_1})^{b_1}\cdots \eta(q^{a_s})^{b_s}$$

Here $\eta$ stands for the Dedekind eta-function.  Using the above defined $\eta_{\sigma}$ we define: 
$$\sum_{j>0}p_{\sigma}(1+j)q^{1+j} = \frac{q}{\eta_{\sigma}(q)}$$
This is a generalized partition function.

We assume the cycle type of $\sigma$ is $1^{1}23^{1}$ and hence $N = 23$. In this case I have the following questions :

1. What is this generalized partition function $p_{\sigma}$ and how to find $p_{\sigma}(n)$ for some natural number $n$?
2. There are many generalisations of partitions functions and hence what is the reference for this particular type of generalized partition function?

Thanks for your time.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have is positive integers such that $\;a_1b_1+\dots+a_sb_s=24.$
Your $q/\eta_\sigma(q)$ is an example of an eta-quotient and is a modular function of negative weight. As just one example, if $\;a_1=1,b_1=24\;$ then $\eta_\sigma(q)=\Delta(q)$ is the generating function of the [Ramanujan tau function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_tau_function). You may find some similar kinds of partitions in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org). For example, sequence [A005758](http://oeis.org/A005758) is partitions into parts of 12 kinds. For your first question, just expand $\;\eta(q^a)=\prod_{n>0}1-q^{an}\;$ and multiply the $q$-series together. For example, in your case where $b_1=b_2=a_1=1, a_2=23,$ 
$$f(q):=\frac1{\prod_{k>0}(1-q^k)(1-q^{23k})}=1+q+2q^2+3q^3+5q^4+\dots$$
which is the generating function of partitions of $n$ into positive integers where the integers come in two kinds and the second kind has weight $23$ times the weight of the first kind.

Answer (score 4):

It is not an answer, but just some comments where such $\eta$ products appear:

- A version of Moonshine for the [Mathieu group M24](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group)  proposed by G. Mason around 1985, the coefficients $a_i, b_i$ are related with the cycle structre of M24 elements ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group_M24#Conjugacy_classes)), in particular (1,23) appears there. 
  The result is that such products are Hecke eigen-forms
- Related theorem by D. Dummit, H. Kisilevsky, and J. McKay, **Multiplicative products of η functions**, Finite Groups - Coming of Age, American Mathematical Society, 1985 which describes all such multiplicative products - (most come form M24).  Nice introduction to that and previous results can be found in Jeremy Booher [The Spirit of Moonshine: Connections between the Mathieu Groups and Modular Forms](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi5xKD1683WAhULGZoKHWK4DgQQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.harvard.edu%2Ftheses%2Fsenior%2Fbooher%2Fbooher.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0MBDdlgZQ9ZptZxf8zU13X)
- McKay conjecture proved by Koike 1984 ([ON McKAY'S CONJECTURE](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0027763000020985)) gives
  conditions on $a_i, b_i$ when such $\eta$-product is primitive cusp form,
  again is quite related to the above mentioned results
- S. Galkin found ([see here](http://research.ipmu.jp/ipmu/sysimg/ipmu/467.pdf)) that Mason's $\eta$-products are related with Gromov-Witten invariants of certain Fano manifolds
- K.Saito considered $\eta$-products in his papers e.g. [Extended Affine Root System V (Elliptic Eta-product and their Dirichlet series)](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~saito/). 
  Some of his conjectures has been proved in [arXiv:math/0702027](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0702027).
  See also MO270241  [Are the Fourier coefficients of η(qm)m/η(q)η(qm)m/η(q) non-negative?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270241/10446)
- MO33058:  [Eta-products and modular elliptic curves](https://mathoverflow.net/q/33058/10446) where elliptic curves
  whose modular are such $\eta$-products are described. See also 
  MO238646 [On η(6z)η(18z)η(6z)η(18z) and the splitting / modularity of x3−2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/238646/10446)
- MO91672 [Linear eta product identities - how many are there?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/91672/10446), MO92119 [Duality of eta product identities: a new idea?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/92119/10446)

Comment: Great answer. I am excited to know there is this much literature behind this question. Thanks.